# Question closed due to homework policy?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, reopen

My post [Is there a steady state for two conductors at different temperatures connected to a battery?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/716162/) was closed under homework policy. Nevertheless it is clear that is not a homework. How do I reopen the question?

Comment: I mean, if it had been clear to the close voters that this does not fall under our homework policy, then the question wouldn't have been closed, so I don't really know what the assertion *"Nevertheless it is clear that is not a homework"* is supposed to mean. Do you understand that our policy does not actually care whether a question originates from a textbook or exercise sheet or not? In general, if a question is closed, you should *edit* it to make it clearer that it shouldn't have been closed. I'm not sure what more specific guidance you're looking for here.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I guess what I am missing in the question was a comment making it clear why it is a homework question

Comment: From [the tag](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info): *"A "homework question" is any question whose value lies in helping you understand the method by which the question can be solved, rather than getting the answer itself. This includes not just questions from actual homework assignments, but also self-study problems, puzzles, etc."*

Comment: @PeterMortensen thanks I guess. that policy seems contradictory and unhelpful in the sense that if I have provided a more detailed system it would have actually looked like a homework and would have been closed with the same policy.

Comment: @Mauricio see https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10938/what-are-good-examples-of-narrowing-a-homework-question-down-to-a-conceptual-que or https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10896/what-does-conceptual-mean or https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12941/low-level-conceptual-questions-closed-as-homework-questions-when-using-hw-questi